# Pandas read_sql: Error converting data type

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I have a relatively simple task of querying a SQL Server database and putting results into a pandas dataframe. But, I am facing some issues that I could not find much about it.

I am hoping this is something obvious that someone can point out and not data dependent.

Consider the SQL query below:

```sql
SELECT tb2.DatasetID, tb2.score1, tb2.score2, tb2.score3, tb2.score4, tb2.score5 
FROM Meta AS tb1 
INNER JOIN Scores AS tb2 ON tb2.DatasetID = tb1.DatasetID 
WHERE tb1.StudyNumber = 217139 
  AND tb1.StudyDescription LIKE '%|55184|%'
```

with two sets of filters

- Filter set 1: `StudyNumber = 217139, StudyDescription ~ 55184` ==> returns 1 row
- Filter set 2: `StudyNumber = 277145, StudyDescription ~ 55296` ==> returns 2 rows

Running these queries directly in SQL Server Management Studio provides 1 row of results for filter 1 and 2 rows for filter 2. I had a quick comparison of results for all three rows and things look quite similar in nature. So, I am ruling out the issue with data.

Now, doing the same through Python code. The code snippet below will take care of the query. It works fine for filter set 1 where 1 row of result is expected.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import json
import pyodbc

connStr = 'Driver=%s; Server=%s;Database=%s;UID=%s; PWD=%s' %(...) # Omitted Credentials
conn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
dbCursor = conn.cursor()

q = "SELECT tb2.DatasetID, tb2.score1, tb2.score2, tb2.score3, tb2.score4, tb2.score5 
FROM Meta as tb1 
INNER JOIN Scores as tb2 
ON tb2.DatasetID=tb1.DatasetID 
WHERE tb1.StudyNumber=?and tb1.StudyDescription like ? "

# ----------------------
# Setting Filters
# ----------------------
# Filter Set 1
study_number= 217139 
study_desc = 55184

# Filter Set 2
# study_number= 277145 
# study_desc = 55296
# ----------------------

param = f'%|{study_desc}|%'
df = pd.read_sql(q, conn, params={study_number, param}, coerce_float=False)
print('Query Completed!')
```

However, running the code with filter set 2 (see above), will raise following error which I am  unclear about. I have tried with both Driver 13 and 17 with no resolution.

> Execution failed on sql '...': ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC
> Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Error converting data type
> nvarchar to bigint. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Interestingly enough, If I replace `pd.read_sql` in the last line with the following approach, there is no error raised with either of filter sets.

```py
dbCursor.execute(q, study_number, param)
df = pd.DataFrame(dbCursor.fetchall())
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with `param`... can't you just use `params={study_number, study_desc}`?

Comment: the `param` is a formatted string composed with integer parameter `study_desc`. The value `study_desc=12345` will  form `param= '%|12345|%'` which is used in `like` filter in query. But, you can ignore and assume a simple params pass.

Comment: You've already got `tbl.StudyDescription like '%|?|%'` in your query, though, so this expands out to `tbl.StudyDescription like '%|%|55184|%|%'`.

Comment: That was a typo while adjusting/cleaning my code to share. It should be just `?` as edited now. Thanks